# 403 Error when calling AWS::S3.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rake

I'm working on a rake task for a Rails 4.0 application in order to copy some old image URLs from outside my website or S3 into S3. I can verify that my credentials are correct and loaded with `printenv`. For some reason though, I get a 403 error every time I run the task. My system time is synced with a reliable time server and the avatars directory I'm attempting to save to in S3 is set to public. Any ideas on what could be causing this? Full rake task code below:

```
namespace :arthackday do
  desc "Grabs old profile pics from participants and saves them to S3."
  task :update_participant_photos  => :environment do
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'aws/s3'

    s3_base_url = "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/arthackday/participants/avatars/"

    Participant.all.each do |participant|
      if participant.photo_url?
        file_name = "#{participant.name.gsub(/ /,"-")}.jpg"
        File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/img/temp/#{file_name}", 'wb') do |fo|
          fo.write open(participant.photo_url).read
        end

        s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
        s3.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']].objects["participants/avatars/#{file_name}"].write(:file => "#{Rails.root}/public/img/temp/#{file_name}")

        participant.photo_url = s3_base_url + file_name
        participant.save!
        puts "New URL for #{participant.name}'s photo: #{participant.photo_url}"
      else
        puts "#{participant.name} does not have a photo_url"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you check if the bucket has permission set correctly?

Comment: It seems to be, and I'm also able to upload different images for other models into different directories in the same bucket using Paperclip.

Comment: Only explanation is that AWS::S3:new is using a different access_key_id, secret_access_key pair.  Have you tried hard coding the keys in your statement?  `s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => 'your_access_key', :secret_access_key => 'your_secret_access_key')`

Comment: Just tried it with hardcoded credentials. Didn't make a difference, sadly.